# How to override WiX default strings without repeating them in each .wxl file?

Tags: wix

I want to override the default dialog title strings with my own single translation for many languages. I can override each string in each locale file like this:

```
<!-- File: 1041.wxl -->
<WixLocalization Culture="ja-jp" ... >
    <!-- My standard title for all the dialogs -->
    <String Id="Installer_Title">[ProductDisplayName] jpjpjp</String>

    <!-- Reuse the string above to override defaults -->
    <String Id="BrowseDlg_Title">!(loc.Installer_Title)</String>
    <String Id="CancelDlg_Title">!(loc.Installer_Title)</String>
    <!-- Etcetera -->
</WixLocalization>
```

But I don't want to add this list to every single locale file I'm delivering. I'd like to include a file of all the strings I want to override like this:

```
<!-- File: 1041.wxl -->
<WixLocalization Culture="ja-jp" ... >
    <!-- My standard title for all the dialogs -->
    <String Id="Installer_Title">[ProductDisplayName] jpjpjp</String>

    <?include AllLanguages.wxl ?>
</WixLocalization>
```

Included file:

```
<!-- File: AllLanguages.wxl -->
<Include>
    <String Id="BrowseDlg_Title">!(loc.Installer_Title)</String>
    <String Id="CancelDlg_Title">!(loc.Installer_Title)</String>
</Include>
```

Unfortunately when I build this the strings defined in AllLanguages.wxl are not seen in the locale and the defaults are not overridden. I tried a similar experiment adding a unique string id to a dialog and into the included file and saw "error LGHT0102 : The localization variable !(loc.xyzzy) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined."

I tried putting the strings in an "anonymous" <WixLocalization/> element but had no success.

Suggestions? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, .wxl files do not support `<?include?>`. `<?include?>` is a compile-time concept and .wxl files are processed at bind time (or runtime).